# Android issue with making phone calls in 4.4 android.permission.CALL_PHONE

Tags: android, permissions

before 4.4 everything was fine with

`<uses-feature
        android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"
        android:required="false" />`

in the manifest. This line was in the manifest to handle permission issues with phones and tablets, so that one app can be used for both tablet and phones.

In 4.4, kitkat, it will allow you to call with third party phone apps but not default dialer unless you change the permission to

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />`

Here's my question, is there a way to play with the manifest that I can have one app for phones and tablets?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This line was in the manifest to handle permission issues with phones and tablets

That line has nothing to do with permissions. It also is incorrect, in that `android.permission.CALL_PHONE` is not a hardware feature that you request via `<uses-feature>`.

If that's a typo in your question, and you really meant `<uses-permission>`, bear in mind that there is no `android:required="false"` on `<uses-permission>`.

> In 4.4, kitkat, it will allow you to call with third party phone apps but not default dialer unless you change the permission to `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />`

That permission has been required for `ACTION_CALL` since Android 1.0.

> Here's my question, is there a way to play with the manifest that I can have one app for phones and tablets?

Have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />` and `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />`, as is covered [in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions).

Comment: Hi, I have add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" /> and <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" /> to my Manifest.xml, but our app still can't call phone on LGE-LG-E980 with KitKat os.